# Did pylon spawn rate increase?

Tags: diablo-iii

With patch 2.3, I've been seeing way more [pylons](http://www.diablowiki.net/Pylons), even 2-3x per [rift](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nephalem_Rifts) (~6-7). I've checked the [official update log](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19814212/patch-230-ptr-patch-notes-8-6-2015), but I didn't see such addition (there is a nerf to it, but nothing more is shown).

Am I just extra-lucky or was it changed with update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive proof that the pylon spawn rates have increased. It's not uncommon to hit 5-8 pylons if you full clear a rift normally.

The amount of enemies needed for a clear has increased, so they may have increased the pylon spawn rate. But there is just no way to know for sure at this moment.

Comment: Nope, I got to that in 2 levels of a rift. There probably would be 20+ in total. This probably is related to "The amount of enemies needed for a clear has increased", which is smth else I noticed too. Thanks for your answer Nephalem!

Comment: If there is a forum post about more people seeing an increase, I'll be sure to update my answer. I'm pretty good on keeping up with all the latest forum posts and reddit posts! Good luck Nephalem.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer Nephalem, let Bul-kathos' power be with you!

Comment: Can confirm that it appears pylons are seen more often, my last night runs had quite a few of them compared to pre-patch